# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable error in python

Tags: python

I am new to python, and have been doing a beginner's course on it.

I came across this piece of code during one of the lecture:

```
import datetime 
DOB=input("Enter the DOB:")
CurrentYear=datetime.datetime.now().year() 
CurrentAge=CurrentYear-int(DOB)
if(CurrentAge>=18):
    print("Your Age is {} and you are Adult".format(CurrentAge))
if(CurrentAge<18):
    print("Your Age is {} and you are not Adult".format(CurrentAge))
print("Condition has been verfied successfully")
```

This course that I am doing is from ~2018, and the instructor didn't have any error while compiling this code.

Comment: What input are you entering?

Comment: Yes, but i am still confused where exactly in this code is int being assinged twice

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now().year` is an int but you do `datetime.datetime.now().year()` - so you try to treat this int as a function

Comment: @SuneeshJacob 1998 , 2000, 2005. trying all ranging from the 90's

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the attribute `year` of `datetime.datetime.now()` is not a function, and so, it doesn't support `year()`. That's why it says that it is not callable. `datetime.datetime.now().year` is in `int` format, and since it is not a function, it is not callable (like this:`.()`).

Change `CurrentYear=datetime.datetime.now().year()` to `CurrentYear=datetime.datetime.now().year`.

The new code would be like this:

```
import datetime 
DOB=input("Enter the DOB:")
CurrentYear=datetime.datetime.now().year
CurrentAge=CurrentYear-int(DOB)
if(CurrentAge>=18):
    print("Your Age is {} and you are Adult".format(CurrentAge))
if(CurrentAge<18):
    print("Your Age is {} and you are not Adult".format(CurrentAge))
print("Condition has been verfied successfully")
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally got the output.

Comment: can you explain what was the issue with the previous code?

Comment: The issue with the previous code is that the attribute `year` of `datetime.datetime.now()` is not a function, and so, it doesn't support `year()`. That's why it says that it is not callable. `datetime.datetime.now().year` is in `int` format, and since it is not a function, it is not callable (like this:`.()`). I will add this info in the answer.

Comment: "year" is an attribute of datetime class not a function. Hence, not callable. To access the attributes you don't have to use "()"

Answer (score 2):

The issue is data types (hence *TypeError*). A data type may be a string, integer, or even a function **(a function is something that is `called`, such as `print()`: notice the brackets)**.

You cannot put the brackets after an integer. That suggests you are trying to run it as a function.

The variable: `datetime.datetime.now().year` is an integer. You cannot run a function from an integer.

> The correction would be from `datetime.datetime.now().year()` → `datetime.datetime.now().year`

The final code looks like this:

```py
import datetime 
DOB=input("Enter the DOB:")
CurrentYear=datetime.datetime.now().year 
CurrentAge=CurrentYear-int(DOB)
if(CurrentAge>=18):
    print("Your Age is {} and you are Adult".format(CurrentAge))
if(CurrentAge<18):
    print("Your Age is {} and you are not Adult".format(CurrentAge))
print("Condition has been verfied successfully")
```

I have tested this thoroughly. Good luck with the rest of your Python course.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. i wasn't able to notice it while coding simultaneously during the course and thus ended up creating a function.

Comment: You are very welcome, @lonewolf303. Data types can be confusing to start with. Geed luck with your Python journey! 